# How to write a oneliner that deletes every file in a given directory except a file with a given name?

Tags: linux

I am trying to write a oneliner (on my ubuntu running on my windows laptop) that deletes every file in a directory, called floop, except the file with a given name, called `file keep me`.

This is what i got already:

```
for foo in /floop;
do
    if [ ! $foo == "file keep me" ];
    then
        rm -r $foo;
    fi;
done
```

The error that im getting is:

```
rm: cannot remove '/floop': No such file or directory
```

At the moment I am trying it in the `floop/` directory itself, because when I tried it in my homedir it deleted the whole folder

Comment: ***Edit*** your question and show the results of `ls -Al`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name 'name of file' -delete
```

---

PS: The correct version of your for loop would be:

```
for foo in /floop/* ; 
do
    # Skip the file you want to keep       
    if [ "$foo" = "/floop/file keep me" ] ;
    then
        continue
    fi

    # Skip directories
    if [ -d "$foo" ] ;
    then
        continue
    fi

    # Remove other files
    rm "$foo"
done
```